# Why are my buttons not getting wider within the layout?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

Usually when I see buttons placed in a Windows and that window is elongated, the buttons on the window also become elongated.

Here is a sample program.

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
  
public class MultiLayoutDemo
{  
    JFrame f;  
    MultiLayoutDemo()
    {
        f=new JFrame();  
          
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    
        ///Top Row
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel(layout);
        jp1.add(buildLayout1());
        jp1.add(buildLayout2());
        jp1.add(buildLayout3());
        f.add(jp1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        ///Bottom Row
        FlowLayout bottomLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(bottomLayout);
        jp2.add(buildLayout4());
        
        f.add(jp2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.setSize(300,300);  
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }
    
    private JPanel buildLayout1() 
    {
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(flowLayout);
        
        jp.add(new JLabel("Name"));
        jp.add(new JButton("First"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Last"));
        
        return jp;
    }

    private JPanel buildLayout2() 
    {
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(flowLayout);
        
        jp.add(new JLabel("Age"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Young "));
        jp.add(new JButton("Old"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Really Old"));
        
        return jp;
    }

    private JPanel buildLayout3() 
    {
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(flowLayout);
        
        jp.add(new JLabel("Location"));
        jp.add(new JButton("North Side "));
        jp.add(new JButton("South Side"));
        
        return jp;
    }

    private JPanel buildLayout4() 
    {
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(flowLayout);
        
        jp.add(new JLabel("Hobbies"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Jogging"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Skydiving"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Racing"));
        jp.add(new JButton("TV"));
        jp.add(new JButton("N/A"));
        
        return jp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  
        new MultiLayoutDemo();  
    }  
}
```

Current results generates this.

[image]

Desired results is the buttons expand something like the following but obviously the Text doesn't get distorted.

[image]

Should I be using a different Layout???
Is there a property to set to allow for dynamic resizing of the buttons?

Comment: From the Oracle tutorial, [How to Use FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html): "The FlowLayout class puts components in a row, sized at their preferred size. If the horizontal space in the container is too small to put all the components in one row, the FlowLayout class uses multiple rows. If the container is wider than necessary for a row of components, the row is, by default, centered horizontally within the container."  If you want to stretch the JButtons, a GridBagLayout would probably work better.

Comment: Oh, JRadioButtons would take less GUI space and perform the same function as your JButtons.

Comment: Does that mean to use the GridBagLayout in the various buildLayout() routines then if added to the Top/Bottom of the BorderLayout it will work??

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want the layout to do.  To me, your layout looks like it should be a form where the JLabels would be lined up vertically on the left and the JRadioButtons would be lined up vertically on the right.  I'd create one JPanel with a GridBagLayout and place the one JPanel in the center of the JFrame.

Comment: The 3 sets of bottoms on top and the 1 set of buttons on the bottom. Basically the lines which consist of 4 button groups. The top should always show the 3 and the bottom should always show the 1.

Comment: I understand how you're trying to layout the JButtons.  I don't think that your desired layout provides a better user experience than what I suggested.

Comment: I agree, but the sample code was just stuff off the top of my head. The actually window requires buttons to be used based on the associated data. The above code is just an example to show that buttons do not get wider.   I have played around and made both buildLayout1() to use a GridBagConstraint as well as the main Frame and the buttons still do not grow.

Comment: There is a screen shot of the desired results above in the original post. Basically the expected results is as the window becomes wider so do the Buttons.

Answer (score 2):

I used some of your code to create the following GUI.

[image: Stretch Flow Layout]

I did not add a `WindowListener` to adjust the `JPanels` if you resize the `JFrame`.  I left that as an exercise for you.

I rearranged the code so that it generally reads from top to bottom, like an essay.  Generally, the most abstract code comes first, then the detailed code comes later.  This ordering makes reading code so much simpler.

I added a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that Swing components are created and executed on the `Event Dispatch Thread`.

I separated out the `JFrame` method from the `JPanel` methods.  This makes the code simpler to understand.

The `stretchPanel` method is the code that stretches the smaller `JPanel`.  I call this method after the `JFrame` `pack` method so Swing has made all of the layout calculations.  I calculate the difference between the larger `JPanel` and the smaller `JPanel` and distribute that difference between the Swing components.

As I said in my comment, I think this type of layout provides a poor user experience.  You also have to deal with `JFrame` resizing yourself, which makes this type of Swing code very brittle.

Here's the complete runnable code.  May God have mercy on your soul.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StretchFlowLayoutExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new StretchFlowLayoutExample());
    }
    
    private JPanel lowerPanel;
    private JPanel upperPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stretch Flow Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        stretchPanel(lowerPanel, upperPanel);
        
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        upperPanel = createUpperPanel();
        lowerPanel = createLowerPanel();
        
        panel.add(upperPanel);
        panel.add(lowerPanel);
        
        Dimension u = upperPanel.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension l = lowerPanel.getPreferredSize();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(u.width, u.height + l.height + 25));
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createUpperPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.add(buildLayout1());
        panel.add(buildLayout2());
        panel.add(buildLayout3());
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel buildLayout1() {
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(flowLayout);

        jp.add(new JLabel("Name"));
        jp.add(new JButton("First"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Last"));

        return jp;
    }

    private JPanel buildLayout2() {
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(flowLayout);

        jp.add(new JLabel("Age"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Young "));
        jp.add(new JButton("Old"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Really Old"));

        return jp;
    }

    private JPanel buildLayout3() {
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(flowLayout);

        jp.add(new JLabel("Location"));
        jp.add(new JButton("North Side "));
        jp.add(new JButton("South Side"));

        return jp;
    }
    
    private JPanel createLowerPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.add(buildLayout4());
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel buildLayout4() {
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(flowLayout);

        jp.add(new JLabel("Hobbies"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Jogging"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Skydiving"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Racing"));
        jp.add(new JButton("TV"));
        jp.add(new JButton("N/A"));

        return jp;
    }
    
    private void stretchPanel(JPanel smallPanel, JPanel largePanel) {
        Dimension l = largePanel.getSize();
        Dimension s = smallPanel.getSize();
        
        Component[] components = smallPanel.getComponents();
        components = ((JPanel) components[0]).getComponents();
        int count = components.length;
        int width = l.width - s.width;
        int extra = width / count;
        int remainder = width % count;
        
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            Component component = components[index];
            Dimension d = component.getSize();
            
            int newWidth = d.width + extra;
            if (remainder > 0) {
                newWidth++;
                remainder--;
            }

            component.setSize(new Dimension(newWidth, d.height));
            component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(newWidth, d.height));
        }
 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but the buttons do not expand with this code. After the JFrame opens there is 1/4 inch of space between the edge of the window and the labels and/or buttons.  After using the mouse to make the window twice as wide. The Buttons and labels all remain the same size. The goal is to have the same 1/4 of space and have the buttons become longer as the window gets wider. In the scenarios I have seen this is done purely with layouts and not window listeners but these layouts are throwing me a curve ball right now.